# Regarding the Day night theme of latest support design library

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-library, android-cardview

I just tried to get my hands on the new Theme style (`Theme.AppCompat.DayNight`) ,It works but it messed up my card background.

How can i change my card background?

Here it's my `v21/styles.xml`

```
<resources>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>

</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>

    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

And my colors.xml of values-night qualifier

```
<resources>
   <color name="primary">#ff01dc53</color>
   <color name="primaryDark">#ff01dc53</color>
   <color name="accent">#01dc53</color>

</resources>
```

MyApplication class :

```
    package com.cyanogen.unofficial.dashboard.util;

import android.app.Application;
import android.app.UiModeManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate;

/**
 * Created by Shiva on 14-03-2016.
 */
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    static {

        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_AUTO);


    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_AUTO);
        }
}
```

Screenshot :

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: What version of AppCompat/Support Library are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [release notes of the revision 23.2.1 of the Support Library](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html), this version fixed [issue 194497](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=194497), adding a dark theme for `CardView`. This is accomplished by using the `CardView.Dark` style.

So you'd declare in your `values/styles.xml`:

```
<style name="CardView.DayNight" parent="CardView.Light />
```

And in your `values-night/styles.xml`:

```
<style name="CardView.DayNight" parent="CardView.Dark" />
```

Then apply it to each `CardView` with `style="@style/CardView.DayNight"`

Comment: Ian, and what about this issue?

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=203469

The 23.2.1 messed up CardView in my project :(